# Cannot Authenticate SPA with passport-azure-ad's Bear Strategy

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, azure-active-directory, adal

So I was playing get `Integrating Azure AD into an AngularJS single page app`
 this tutorial to work. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-angular-node

It is implemented for the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, but unfortunately my organization does not support the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, therefore I replaced the experimental version of `adal.js` and `adal-angular` libraries with GA `adal.js` and `adal-angular`libraries. The front-end authentication works perfect. However after I modified the back-end config based on `passport-azure-ad`. The back-end failed to authenticate the tokens that was implicitly granted.

I have set the `allow implicit flow` to true in the manifest file. Also I tried to use my `client ID` and `Tenant Name` in another example that uses the same `angular` front end but `.NET` as the back-end. It worked!

Here is my back-end config

```
exports.creds = {

    // The app id you get from the registration portal
    audience: 'http://localhost:8080',
    clientID: '**********************************',

    // Passport will use this URL to fetch the token validation information from Azure AD
    identityMetadata: '************************************',
    // Required.
    // If you are using the common endpoint, you should either set `validateIssuer` to false, or provide a value for `issuer`.
    validateIssuer: true,

    // Required.
    // Set to true if you use `function(req, token, done)` as the verify callback.
    // Set to false if you use `function(req, token)` as the verify callback.
    passReqToCallback: false,

    // Required if you are using common endpoint and setting `validateIssuer` to true.
    // For tenant-specific endpoint, this field is optional, we will use the issuer from the metadata by default.
    issuer: '**************************************',

    isB2C: false,

    // Optional. Default value is false.
    // Set to true if you accept access_token whose `aud` claim contains multiple values.
    allowMultiAudiencesInToken: false,

    // Optional. 'error', 'warn' or 'info'
    loggingLevel: 'info'
};
```

My server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Pull in the Azure AD bearer passport strategy
var OIDCBearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;

// This object is used for in-memory data storage, instead of a database.
// Each time you run the server, you will get a fresh, empty list.
var tasks = [];

// Load passport and configure it to use Azure AD Bearer auth
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.use(new OIDCBearerStrategy({
    identityMetadata: config.creds.identityMetadata,
    audience: config.creds.audience,
    clientID: config.creds.clientID,
    validateIssuer: true,
    issuer: config.creds.issuer,

}, function (token, done) {
    console.log("yooo");
    return done(null, token, null);
}));

var router = express.Router();
router.route('/api/tasks')
    .post(passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }), controller)
```

Here is the output from my browser console after the front-end authenticated:

```
State: **************
adal.js:973 State status:true
adal.js:973 State is right
```

Has anybody done similar things?

Comment: Can you confirm that you've specified the v1 endpoint for the metadata? login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: Yes! Actually the problem is that "audience" property in the config should be same as the client ID

Comment: @Rui post that as the answer and accept it if that resolved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody have trouble getting it started with Angularjs1 + Nodejs + adal.js v1.x

Here is an working example. Just change the values in the config.js and app.js

https://github.com/lightertu/Azure-ActiveDirectory-V1-Angularjs-Nodejs-SPA-Sample

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above by the Author of this question, the audience value in the config should be the client ID.